# After clear:both, float div don't go to the top

Tags: css, css-float

I'm making a responsive website and I'm using “float” and “clear: both” to put all the divs in their respective places. But after using “clear: both”, the “div 6” does not go to the top on the right side. To clarify (image):

[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjLlF.png)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
<div class="div4">4</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div5">5</div>
<div class="div6">6</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clear
{
clear:both;
}

.container
{
width: 100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
display:table;
background-color:#CCC;
}

.div1
{
background-color:#FF0;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div1
{
background-color:#FF0;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div2
{
background-color:#FC0;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div2
{
background-color:#FC0;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div3
{
background-color:#F90;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div3
{
background-color:#F90;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div4
{
background-color:#F60;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div4
{
background-color:#F60;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div5
{
background-color:#0C6;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:80px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div5
{
background-color:#0C6;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:80px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div6
{
background-color:#396;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div6
{
background-color:#396;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}
```

I imagine it is a simple solution but I'm having a big deal of trouble trying to solve this.

Please help me!

Comment: In the media selector div6 class you have the value for float set to left.

Comment: Just on mobile version, wich is correct.